# Mortgage calculator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, inheritance

I'm learning JavaScript and decided to build [this mortgage calculator](http://oracleofnj.github.io/mortgage-calculator/) as a starting point. For the most part it was reasonably straightforward, but when I implemented the graphs using D3 I found myself with two similar functions that contained a lot of the same code. I could have used one of the many D3-based charting libraries but the point of this exercise was to learn.

Although this came up in a D3 context, my question is about JavaScript as opposed to D3.

I attempted to refactor it in three different ways:

1. Initialize an object by passing in custom functions that took a reference to the object as an argument
2. Object inheritance via `Object.create`
3. Object composition using a closure for the inner object

They all work but I'm not thrilled about any of them. The first one should probably have been done with more `this` and `bind` and less `my` and `obj` but still wouldn't really feel great. The second one is probably the simplest but made me a little nervous because of the need to use `.bind(this)`. The third one didn't fully eliminate all of the code repetition because using a closure for the inner object made it hard for the non-repeated code to do its job.

Please let me know what you think of the various methods and if you have a better suggestion for how to implement this. Again, the point is to understand JS better and not to actually implement (or use) a D3 charting library.

```
var mtgCharts = (function() {
    function pAndIChart(chartID) {
        var margin = {top: 10, right: 36, bottom: 50, left: 72},
            width, height,
            x = d3.time.scale(),
            y = d3.scale.linear();

        function setSizeAndScales() {
            width = parseInt(d3.select('#'+chartID).style('width'), 10) - margin.left - margin.right;
            height = parseInt(d3.select('#'+chartID).style('height'), 10) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            x.range([0, width]);
            y.range([height, 0]);
        }

        setSizeAndScales();

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient('bottom')
            .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b-%y'));

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient('left');

        var chart = d3.select('#' + chartID)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

        var gXAxis = chart.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')');

        var gYAxis = chart.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'y axis');

        var resize = function() {
            setSizeAndScales();
            gXAxis
                .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll('text')
                .style('text-anchor', 'end')
                .attr('dx', '-1em')
                .attr('dy', '-0.6em')
                .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'rotate(-90)'});

            gYAxis.call(yAxis);
            var paymentMonths = chart.selectAll('.paymentMonth');
            paymentMonths
                .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + x(d.paymentDate.toDate()) + ',0)';});

            chart.selectAll('.bar')
                .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.yHigh); })
                .attr('height', function(d) { return y(d.yLow) - y(d.yHigh); })
                .attr('width', width/paymentMonths.size())
                .style('fill', function(d) {return d.color;});
        };

        var draw = function(amSched) {
            x.domain(d3.extent(amSched.map(function(d) { return d.paymentDate.toDate(); })));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(amSched, function(d) { return d.interest + d.principal; })]);

            var paymentMonths = chart.selectAll('.paymentMonth').data(amSched);

            paymentMonths
                .enter().append('g')
                .attr('class', 'paymentMonth');

            paymentMonths.exit().remove();

            var bars = paymentMonths.selectAll('.bar')
                .data(function(d) {
                    return [{color: 'IndianRed', yLow: 0, yHigh: d.principal},
                            {color: 'SteelBlue', yLow: d.principal, yHigh: d.interest + d.principal}];
                });

            bars.enter().append('rect')
                .attr('class', 'bar')
            bars.exit().remove();

            resize();
        }
        d3.select(window).on('resize.' + chartID, resize);
        return {draw: draw};
    }

    function balanceChart(chartID) {
        var margin = {top: 10, right: 36, bottom: 50, left: 72},
            width, height,
            x = d3.time.scale(),
            y = d3.scale.linear();

        function setSizeAndScales() {
            width = parseInt(d3.select('#'+chartID).style('width'), 10) - margin.left - margin.right;
            height = parseInt(d3.select('#'+chartID).style('height'), 10) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            x.range([0, width]);
            y.range([height, 0]);
        }

        setSizeAndScales();

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient('bottom')
            .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b-%y'));

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient('left');

        var yGrid = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient('left')
            .tickFormat("");

        var chart = d3.select('#' + chartID)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

        var gXAxis = chart.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')');

        var gYAxis = chart.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'y axis');

        var gYTicks = chart.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'grid');

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) {return x(d.paymentDate.toDate());})
            .y(function(d) {return y(d.endingBalance);});

        var resize = function() {
            setSizeAndScales();
            gXAxis
                .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll('text')
                .style('text-anchor', 'end')
                .attr('dx', '-1em')
                .attr('dy', '-0.6em')
                .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'rotate(-90)'});

            gYAxis.call(yAxis);
            yGrid.tickSize(-width, 0, 0);
            gYTicks.call(yGrid);
            chart.select('#balanceLine').attr('d', line);
        };

        var draw = function(amSched) {
            x.domain(d3.extent(amSched.map(function(d) { return d.paymentDate.toDate(); })));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(amSched, function(d) { return d.endingBalance; })]);
            chart.select('#balanceLine').remove();
            chart.append('path')
                .datum(amSched)
                .attr('class', 'line')
                .attr('id', 'balanceLine');

            resize();
        };

        d3.select(window).on('resize.' + chartID, resize);
        return {
            draw: draw,
            resize: resize
        };
    }
    return {
        pAndIChart: pAndIChart,
        balanceChart: balanceChart
    };
})();
```

Functions taking `obj` passed in during instantiation: (PS: I am aware of the bug in this one and the next one involving my `config` object if `config.margin.top` etc. is 0.)

```
var mtgCharts = (function() {
    function genericChart(chartID, config) {
        var my = {};

        my.margin = {
            top: (config.margin && config.margin.top) || 10,
            right: (config.margin && config.margin.right) || 36,
            bottom: (config.margin && config.margin.bottom) || 50,
            left: (config.margin && config.margin.left) || 72
        };

        my.gridlines = {
            x: false,
            y: (config.gridlines && (config.gridlines.y === true)) || false
        }

        my.customFns = {
            resize: (config.customFns && config.customFns.resize) || function(){},
            draw: (config.customFns && config.customFns.draw) || function(){},
            yDomain: (config.customFns && config.customFns.yDomain) || function() {return 0;}
        };

        my.x = d3.time.scale();
        my.y = d3.scale.linear();

        my.chart = d3.select('#'+chartID);

        my.setSizeAndScales = function () {
            my.width = parseInt(my.chart.style('width'), 10) - my.margin.left - my.margin.right;
            my.height = parseInt(my.chart.style('height'), 10) - my.margin.top - my.margin.bottom;

            my.x.range([0, my.width]);
            my.y.range([my.height, 0]);
        }
        my.setSizeAndScales();

        my.xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(my.x)
            .orient('bottom')
            .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b-%y'));

        my.yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(my.y)
            .orient('left');

        my.yGrid = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(my.y)
            .orient('left')
            .tickFormat("");

        my.innerChart = my.chart
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + my.margin.left + ',' + my.margin.top + ')');

        my.gXAxis = my.innerChart.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + my.height + ')');

        my.gYAxis = my.innerChart.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'y axis');

        if (my.gridlines.y) {
            my.gYTicks = my.innerChart.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'grid');
        }

        my.resize = function () {
            my.setSizeAndScales();
            my.gXAxis
                .call(my.xAxis)
                .selectAll('text')
                .style('text-anchor', 'end')
                .attr('dx', '-1em')
                .attr('dy', '-0.6em')
                .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'rotate(-90)'});

            my.gYAxis.call(my.yAxis);
            my.yGrid.tickSize(-my.width, 0, 0);
            if (my.gridlines.y) {
                my.gYTicks.call(my.yGrid);
            }
            my.customFns.resize(my);
        }

        my.draw = function(amSched) {
            my.x.domain(d3.extent(amSched.map(function(d) { return d.paymentDate.toDate(); })));
            my.y.domain([0, d3.max(amSched, my.customFns.yDomain)]);

            my.customFns.draw(my, amSched);
            my.resize();
        }
        d3.select(window).on('resize.' + chartID, my.resize);
        return {draw: my.draw};
    }

    function pAndIChart(chartID) {
        var my = genericChart(chartID, {
            customFns: {
                draw: function(obj, data) {
                    var paymentMonths = obj.innerChart.selectAll('.paymentMonth').data(data);

                    paymentMonths
                        .enter().append('g')
                        .attr('class', 'paymentMonth');

                    paymentMonths.exit().remove();

                    var bars = paymentMonths.selectAll('.bar')
                        .data(function(d) {
                            return [{color: 'IndianRed', yLow: 0, yHigh: d.principal},
                                    {color: 'SteelBlue', yLow: d.principal, yHigh: d.interest + d.principal}];
                        });

                    bars.enter().append('rect')
                        .attr('class', 'bar')
                    bars.exit().remove();
                },
                resize: function(obj) {
                    var paymentMonths = obj.innerChart.selectAll('.paymentMonth');

                    paymentMonths
                        .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + obj.x(d.paymentDate.toDate()) + ',0)';});

                    obj.innerChart.selectAll('.bar')
                        .attr('y', function(d) { return obj.y(d.yHigh); })
                        .attr('height', function(d) { return obj.y(d.yLow) - obj.y(d.yHigh); })
                        .attr('width', obj.width/paymentMonths.size())
                        .style('fill', function(d) {return d.color;});
                },
                yDomain: function(d) {
                    return d.interest + d.principal;
                }
            }
        });
        return my;
    };

    function balanceChart(chartID) {
        var my = genericChart(chartID, {
            customFns: {
                draw: function(obj, data) {
                    obj.innerChart.select('#balanceLine').remove();
                    obj.innerChart.append('path')
                        .datum(data)
                        .attr('class', 'line')
                        .attr('id', 'balanceLine');
                },
                resize: function(obj) {
                    var line = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function(d) {return obj.x(d.paymentDate.toDate());})
                        .y(function(d) {return obj.y(d.endingBalance);});
                    obj.innerChart.select('#balanceLine').attr('d', line);
                },
                yDomain: function(d) {
                    return d.endingBalance;
                }
            }
        });
        return my;
    };
    return {
        pAndIChart : pAndIChart,
        balanceChart : balanceChart
    };
})();
```

Object inheritance via Object.create (PS: I am aware of the bug in this one and the previous one involving my `config` object if `config.margin.top` etc. is 0.)

```
var mtgCharts = (function() {
    var baseChart = {
        init: function(chartID, config) {
            this.margin = {
                top: (config.margin && config.margin.top)       || 10,
                right: (config.margin && config.margin.right)   || 36,
                bottom: (config.margin && config.margin.bottom) || 50,
                left: (config.margin && config.margin.left)     || 72
            };
            this.gridlines = (config.gridlines === true)        || false;
            this.outerChart = d3.select('#' + chartID);
            this.x = d3.time.scale();
            this.y = d3.scale.linear();
            this.setSizeAndScales();
            this.xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(this.x)
                .orient('bottom')
                .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b-%y'));

            this.yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(this.y)
                .orient('left');

            this.yGrid = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(this.y)
                .orient('left')
                .tickFormat("");

            this.chart = this.outerChart
                .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')');

            this.gXAxis = this.chart.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'x axis')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + this.height + ')');

            this.gYAxis = this.chart.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'y axis');

            if (this.gridlines) {
                this.gYTicks = this.chart.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'grid');
            }
            d3.select(window).on('resize.' + chartID, this.resize.bind(this));
        },
        setSizeAndScales: function() {
            this.width = parseInt(this.outerChart.style('width'), 10) - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
            this.height = parseInt(this.outerChart.style('height'), 10) - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

            this.x.range([0, this.width]);
            this.y.range([this.height, 0]);
        },
        resize: function() {
            this.setSizeAndScales();
            this.gXAxis
                .call(this.xAxis)
                .selectAll('text')
                .style('text-anchor', 'end')
                .attr('dx', '-1em')
                .attr('dy', '-0.6em')
                .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'rotate(-90)'});

            this.gYAxis.call(this.yAxis);
            if (this.gridlines) {
                this.yGrid.tickSize(-this.width, 0, 0);
                this.gYTicks.call(this.yGrid);
            }
            this.customResize();
        },
        draw: function(data) {
            this.x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.paymentDate.toDate(); })));
            this.y.domain([0, d3.max(data, this.customYDomain)]);
            this.customDraw(data);
            this.resize();
        }
    };
    function pAndIChart(chartID) {
        var chart = Object.create(baseChart);
        chart.customResize = function() {
            var paymentMonths = this.chart.selectAll('.paymentMonth');
            paymentMonths
                .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + chart.x(d.paymentDate.toDate()) + ',0)';});

            this.chart.selectAll('.bar')
                .attr('y', function(d) { return chart.y(d.yHigh); })
                .attr('height', function(d) { return chart.y(d.yLow) - chart.y(d.yHigh); })
                .attr('width', this.width/paymentMonths.size())
                .style('fill', function(d) {return d.color;});
        }
        chart.customDraw = function(amSched) {
            var paymentMonths = this.chart.selectAll('.paymentMonth').data(amSched);

            paymentMonths
                .enter().append('g')
                .attr('class', 'paymentMonth');

            paymentMonths.exit().remove();

            var bars = paymentMonths.selectAll('.bar')
                .data(function(d) {
                    return [{color: 'IndianRed', yLow: 0, yHigh: d.principal},
                            {color: 'SteelBlue', yLow: d.principal, yHigh: d.interest + d.principal}];
                });

            bars.enter().append('rect')
                .attr('class', 'bar')
            bars.exit().remove();
        }
        chart.customYDomain = function(d) {return d.interest + d.principal;};
        chart.init(chartID, {});
        return chart;
    }

    function balanceChart(chartID) {
        var chart = Object.create(baseChart);
        chart.line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) {return chart.x(d.paymentDate.toDate());})
            .y(function(d) {return chart.y(d.endingBalance);});
        chart.customResize = function() {
            this.chart.select('#balanceLine').attr('d', chart.line);
        }
        chart.customDraw = function(amSched) {
            this.chart.select('#balanceLine').remove();
            this.chart.append('path')
                .datum(amSched)
                .attr('class', 'line')
                .attr('id', 'balanceLine');
        }
        chart.customYDomain = function(d) {return d.endingBalance;};
        chart.init(chartID, {gridlines: true});
        return chart;
    }
    return {
        pAndIChart: pAndIChart,
        balanceChart: balanceChart
    };
})();
```

Composition using a closure for the inner object:

```
var mtgCharts = (function() {
    // Inspired by Rob Moore's examples here at
    // http://www.toptal.com/d3-js/towards-reusable-d3-js-charts
    // and http://bl.ocks.org/rcmoore38/9f2908455355c0589619

    function genericChart() {
        var margin = {top: 10, right: 36, bottom: 50, left: 72};
        var dimensions = {width: 0, height: 0};
        var scales = {x: d3.time.scale(), y: d3.scale.linear()};
        var axes = {
            x:      d3.svg.axis().scale(scales.x).orient('bottom').tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b-%y')),
            y:      d3.svg.axis().scale(scales.y).orient('left'),
            grid:   d3.svg.axis().scale(scales.y).orient('left').tickFormat('')
        };
        var gridlines = false;
        var domElements = {};
        function setSizeAndScales() {
            dimensions.width = parseInt(domElements.outerChart.style('width'), 10) - margin.left - margin.right;
            dimensions.height = parseInt(domElements.outerChart.style('height'), 10) - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            scales.x.range([0, dimensions.width]);
            scales.y.range([dimensions.height, 0]);
        }
        function drawAxes() {
            domElements.gXAxis
                .call(axes.x)
                .selectAll('text')
                .style('text-anchor', 'end')
                .attr('dx', '-1em')
                .attr('dy', '-0.6em')
                .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'rotate(-90)'});

            domElements.gYAxis.call(axes.y);
            if (gridlines) {
                axes.grid.tickSize(-dimensions.width, 0, 0);
                gYTicks.call(axes.grid);
            }
        }
        function chart(selection) {
            domElements.outerChart = selection;
            setSizeAndScales();
            domElements.chart = domElements.outerChart.append('g')
                                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
            domElements.gXAxis = domElements.chart.append('g').attr('class', 'x axis')
                                    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + dimensions.height + ')');
            domElements.gYAxis = domElements.chart.append('g').attr('class', 'y axis');
            if (gridlines) {
                domElements.gYTicks = domElements.chart.append('g').attr('class', 'grid');
            }
        }
        chart.setSizeAndScales = setSizeAndScales;
        chart.drawAxes = drawAxes;
        chart.domElements = domElements;
        chart.scales = scales;
        chart.dimensions = dimensions;
        return chart;
    }

    function pAndIChart(chartID) {
        var chart = genericChart();
        d3.select('#' + chartID).call(chart);

        var resize = function() {
            chart.setSizeAndScales();
            chart.drawAxes();
            var paymentMonths = chart.domElements.chart.selectAll('.paymentMonth');
            paymentMonths
                .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + chart.scales.x(d.paymentDate.toDate()) + ',0)';})
                .selectAll('.bar')
                .attr('y', function(d) { return chart.scales.y(d.yHigh); })
                .attr('height', function(d) { return chart.scales.y(d.yLow) - chart.scales.y(d.yHigh); })
                .attr('width', chart.dimensions.width/paymentMonths.size())
                .style('fill', function(d) {return d.color;});
        };

        var draw = function(amSched) {
            chart.scales.x.domain(d3.extent(amSched.map(function(d) { return d.paymentDate.toDate(); })));
            chart.scales.y.domain([0, d3.max(amSched, function(d) { return d.interest + d.principal; })]);

            var paymentMonths = chart.domElements.chart.selectAll('.paymentMonth').data(amSched);

            paymentMonths
                .enter().append('g')
                .attr('class', 'paymentMonth');

            paymentMonths.exit().remove();

            var bars = paymentMonths.selectAll('.bar')
                .data(function(d) {
                    return [{color: 'IndianRed', yLow: 0, yHigh: d.principal},
                            {color: 'SteelBlue', yLow: d.principal, yHigh: d.interest + d.principal}];
                });

            bars.enter().append('rect')
                .attr('class', 'bar')
            bars.exit().remove();

            resize();
        }
        d3.select(window).on('resize.' + chartID, resize);
        return {draw: draw};
    }

    function balanceChart(chartID) {
        var chart = genericChart();
        d3.select('#' + chartID).call(chart);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) {return chart.scales.x(d.paymentDate.toDate());})
            .y(function(d) {return chart.scales.y(d.endingBalance);});

        var resize = function() {
            chart.setSizeAndScales();
            chart.drawAxes();
            chart.domElements.chart.select('#balanceLine').attr('d', line);
        };

        var draw = function(amSched) {
            chart.scales.x.domain(d3.extent(amSched.map(function(d) { return d.paymentDate.toDate(); })));
            chart.scales.y.domain([0, d3.max(amSched, function(d) { return d.endingBalance; })]);
            chart.domElements.chart.select('#balanceLine').remove();
            chart.domElements.chart.append('path')
                .datum(amSched)
                .attr('class', 'line')
                .attr('id', 'balanceLine');

            resize();
        };

        d3.select(window).on('resize.' + chartID, resize);
        return {draw: draw};
    }
    return {
        pAndIChart: pAndIChart,
        balanceChart: balanceChart
    };
})();
```